# How to position a view using Auto Layout anchors outside the screen

Tags: swift, anchor, nslayoutconstraint

How do i position a view using Auto Layout anchors outside the screen to the right? I want to animate it later in to center position.

```
func setup(){
    _ = firstNameTextField.anchor(nil, 
                                  left: view.leftAnchor, 
                                bottom: lastnameTextField.topAnchor, 
                                 right: view.rightAnchor, 
                           topConstant: 16, 
                          leftConstant: 16, 
                        bottomConstant: 8, 
                         rightConstant: 16, 
                         widthConstant: 0, 
                        heightConstant: 46)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be beneficial to explicitly define your constraints, rather than using a "helper" func... it can make it easier for you to understand what's going on.

That said, you want the `left` anchor of your field to be constrained to the `right` anchor of your view, which will put it "off-screen". You can then change that to animate the field into view... "slide it in from the right".

To do that, create a "start" constraint and an "end" constraint:

```
// starting constraint will be leading edge of field 16-pts to the right of view's right edge (off-screen)
firstNameLeadingConstraintStart = firstNameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0)

// ending constraint will be leading edge of field 16-pts from view's left edge
firstNameLeadingConstraintEnd   = firstNameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0)
```

To animate it into view:

```
    // de-activate starting constraint
    self.firstNameLeadingConstraintStart.isActive = false

    // activate ending constraint
    self.firstNameLeadingConstraintEnd.isActive = true

    // animate the change
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Here is a basic example. It includes a button to trigger the animation:

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstNameTextField: UITextField = {
        let v = UITextField()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        v.backgroundColor = .orange  // to make it easy to see
        return v
    }()

    var button: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    // constraint for starting position of field
    var firstNameLeadingConstraintStart: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // constraint for ending position of field
    var firstNameLeadingConstraintEnd: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.addSubview(firstNameTextField)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // top of field 16-pts from top of view
            firstNameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),

            // width of field should be width of view minus 32 (16-pts padding on each side)
            firstNameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -32.0),

            // height of field 46-pts
            firstNameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46.0),

            ])

        // starting constraint will be leading edge of field 16-pts to the right of view's right edge (off-screen)
        firstNameLeadingConstraintStart = firstNameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0)

        // ending constraint will be leading edge of field 16-pts from view's left edge
        firstNameLeadingConstraintEnd   = firstNameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0)

        // activate the starting constraint
        firstNameLeadingConstraintStart.isActive = true

        // add a button so we can trigger the animation
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            ])
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func animateField() -> Void {

        // de-activate starting constraint
        self.firstNameLeadingConstraintStart.isActive = false

        // activate ending constraint
        self.firstNameLeadingConstraintEnd.isActive = true

        // animate the change
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        animateField()
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i know, but i dont know how to make it just outside the screen.

Comment: OK - you need a couple other changes, because you're also setting a "right anchor".  Do you want the field to be the full width of the view, with padding of 16-pts on each side?

Comment: i want i to animate in and be be 16pts from left and right view